# Removing function on server which delete array with bunch IDs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have an app that looks like this [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1b7k.png)

I choose checkboxes and after I press mass delete and in state I have array of ids which I have chosen ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g87Zr.png))
My delete function in controllers looks the following

```
const deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { id: productId } = req.params;
  const product = await Product.findOne({ _id: productId });
  console.log(product);

  if (!product) {
    throw new Error(`No product with ${productId}`);
  }
  await product.remove();
  res.status(200).json({ msg: "Success, product removed" });
};
```

But this function works in postman only on route

```
router.route("/:id").delete(deleteProduct)
```

How to write a function which takes the array of items and a route for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, its unclear what method do you use (POST or GET) ?

##### GET method:

URL example

```
my-api/products?array[]=1&array[]=2&array[]=3
```

Then you can read `array` variable as follows:

```
route.get('my-api/products', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.query.array); // [1, 2, 3]
})
```

##### POST method:

You have to send POST request to your endpoint (e.g. with `axios`):

```
axios.post('my-api/products', {
   selectedItems: [] // your array of ids
})
```

then read `ids` array

```
route.post('my-api/products', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body.selectedItems); // [1, 2, 3]
})
```